# Convert Pipe separated data and transpose

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQl have below data
Table have single column named UNKNOWN_COLUMN

```
UNKNOWN_COLUMN
NSE_EMP nse_cm|NRML|EMPL_NDES|EMPL_DES|EMPL_DES_DESGREY|EMPLOYEE_DES_GREY|EMPLOYEE_NONDES|EMPL_NDES_DES|EMPL_DES_NDES|EMPL_NDES_DESGREY|EMPLOYEE_DES 
BSE bse_cm|NRML|RET_MTM|PLATINUM_DELY|EMPL_NDES|RET_ESOP_CASH|PCG_RMC_USD_100|PCG_RMC|PCG_RMC_USD_5000|PCG_RMC_LDO_USD_10000|RET_NAP|PCG_RMC_10|GOLD_CDS_SB|EMPL_DES|NRINONPINS|EMPL_DES_DESGREY|SUPER_PLATINUM_CDS|RET_CR_MTM|EMPLOYEE_DES_GREY|RET_SPAN_V2|PATINUM_V2|EMPLOYEE_NONDES|FNATIONAL|RET_PENAL|RET_ESOP|EMPL_NDES_DESGREY_LAS|PCG_RMC_SL|EMPL_NDES_DES|ESOP|PCG_RMC_SOL_10L|PCG_RMC_USD_1000|PCG_ONLYSPAN|PCG_RMC_USD_10000|ESOPHEDGE|HL_MIS_EBLCAS_MTM|PCG_RMC_LDO|EMPL_DES_GREY|EOSP|EMPL_DES_NDES|EMPL_NDES_DESGREY|RET_SPAN_PENAL|PCG_RMC_SOL_25L|RET_TEST|PLATINUM|NRIPINS|RET_INDIRECT|PCG_RMC_USD_2500|EMPLOYEE_NONDES_WAIS|RET_LDO|HLPRO|PLATINUM_SB|GOLD_CDS|CASH_CAS|GOLD|RET_SPAN_MTM|PCG_ONLYSPAN_10|PCG_LDO_USD_15000|RET_NONTRADER_SB|PLATINUM_CDS|EMPLOYEE_DES|PCG_RMC_SL_SPAN|HL_EBLCAS_MTM|CDS
```

Table can have multiple rows
Data in Each row have "|"

I wanted to seperate rows by "|" and transpose the data in to new column
No of  "|" in "|" is not fixed

Request you to provide SQL Query when i can convert data into column and transpose the same

Comment: Is this a one-off need, or an ongoing requirement?  If it's a one-off, you'd probably find it a heck of a lot quicker to just get the data into Excel and then import to SQL from there

Comment: that i know about excel..but its ongoing requirement

Comment: If you are using `SQL Server 2022` you can use [string_split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with `enable_ordinal`

Comment: So for the example data provided, you are looking for a table that has two rows and [max number of pipes that appears in any row-1] columns, with the first row having only the first 11 columns populated with the rest of the columns having NULL values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use STRING_SPLIT to generate the parsed data, like :

```
CREATE TABLE #T (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, UNKNOWN_COLUMN VARCHAR(max));
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('NSE_EMP nse_cm|NRML|EMPL_NDES|EMPL_DES|EMPL_DES_DESGREY|EMPLOYEE_DES_GREY|EMPLOYEE_NONDES|EMPL_NDES_DES|EMPL_DES_NDES|EMPL_NDES_DESGREY|EMPLOYEE_DES 
BSE bse_cm|NRML|RET_MTM|PLATINUM_DELY|EMPL_NDES|RET_ESOP_CASH|PCG_RMC_USD_100|PCG_RMC|PCG_RMC_USD_5000|PCG_RMC_LDO_USD_10000|RET_NAP|PCG_RMC_10|GOLD_CDS_SB|EMPL_DES|NRINONPINS|EMPL_DES_DESGREY|SUPER_PLATINUM_CDS|RET_CR_MTM|EMPLOYEE_DES_GREY|RET_SPAN_V2|PATINUM_V2|EMPLOYEE_NONDES|FNATIONAL|RET_PENAL|RET_ESOP|EMPL_NDES_DESGREY_LAS|PCG_RMC_SL|EMPL_NDES_DES|ESOP|PCG_RMC_SOL_10L|PCG_RMC_USD_1000|PCG_ONLYSPAN|PCG_RMC_USD_10000|ESOPHEDGE|HL_MIS_EBLCAS_MTM|PCG_RMC_LDO|EMPL_DES_GREY|EOSP|EMPL_DES_NDES|EMPL_NDES_DESGREY|RET_SPAN_PENAL|PCG_RMC_SOL_25L|RET_TEST|PLATINUM|NRIPINS|RET_INDIRECT|PCG_RMC_USD_2500|EMPLOYEE_NONDES_WAIS|RET_LDO|HLPRO|PLATINUM_SB|GOLD_CDS|CASH_CAS|GOLD|RET_SPAN_MTM|PCG_ONLYSPAN_10|PCG_LDO_USD_15000|RET_NONTRADER_SB|PLATINUM_CDS|EMPLOYEE_DES|PCG_RMC_SL_SPAN|HL_EBLCAS_MTM|CDS');

SELECT ID, value
FROM   #T
       CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(UNKNOWN_COLUMN, '|')
```

That gives :

```
ID          value
----------- --------------------
1           NSE_EMP nse_cm
1           NRML
1           EMPL_NDES
1           EMPL_DES
1           EMPL_DES_DESGREY
1           EMPLOYEE_DES_GREY
1           EMPLOYEE_NONDES
1           EMPL_NDES_DES
1           EMPL_DES_NDES
```

Evidemment, il serait intéressant de convertir cette horreur qui viole la première forme normale en table afin de bénéficier de performances... Est_ce que cela viens de Windev ???